# What does the "kubernetes.io/container/cpu/core_usage_time" metric measure?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

The [Google Cloud Monitoring documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes) says `container/cpu/core_usage_time` is:

> Cumulative CPU usage on all cores used by the container in seconds.
> Sampled every 60 seconds.

This description says the CPU usage is sampled every minute but it doesn't say the window of time over which the cumulative CPU usage is measured.

Is this the number of seconds the CPU cores were active over the last minute? That is, if the value of this metric is 150, does that mean the CPU utilization is 150 core-seconds / 60 seconds = 2.5 cores (2500 millicores)?

Comment: [Cpu/usage](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/heapster/blob/master/docs/storage-schema.md) metric is "Cumulative amount of consumed CPU time on all cores in nanoseconds"  and is measured over time -- it's the amount of time that the process was running on the given processor, so if your pod was running for at 500 millicores for 2 seconds, you'd have a usage of 1 second.  However if that’s not the case, could you please clarify your question, I'm a bit lost on your question?

Answer (score 0):

the `container/cpu/core_usage_time` is a metric that measures the amount of CPU time consumed by a specific core in a container within a Kubernetes cluster (in this case).

it tracks core-specific usage time that data help in about how efficiently CPU resources are being utilized by containers .so it keeps monitoring and optimizing resource utilization by cpu at the core level efficiently, it will help in performance, scalability, and cost-effectiveness in the Kubernetes deployment.

for ref see [metrics_anthos](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_anthos)